# C++11 Call virtual member function

Tags: c++11

I`m trying to implement something like this using C++11.

```
class Proto{
public:    
    virtual void fu() = 0;
};

class Impl: public Proto{
public:
    void fu();
};

void Impl::fu(){
    LOG_INFO("im fu");
}

class Inv{
public:
    void useFu(void (Proto::*)());
};

void Inv::useFu(void (Proto::*fu)()){
    //fu();
};

void main(){    
    Impl impl;
    Inv inv;

    //inv.useFu(impl.fu); 
}
```

`useFu(void (Proto::*)())` must be declared in this way because, `fu()` uses some specific to `Proto` functionality's

I have two places were things going wrong.
First is `fu()` call itself and second how to pass fu as parameter `inv.useFu(impl.fu)`.

**Edit after [bipll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749717/bipll) answer**

The suggested usage of `inv.useFu()` solves the second problem of my question.

```
inv.useFu(static_cast<void (Proto::*)(void)>(&Impl::fu));
```

But I still need to call `fu` as a pointer to member function;

Answer (score 0):

The way your `useFu` is declared now, it should be called as

```cpp
inv.useFu(static_cast<void (Proto::*)(void)>(&Impl::fu));
```

But I guess that's not what you wanted. It should rather be

```cpp
template<class F> void useFu(F &&f) { std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f)); }
```

or simply

```cpp
void useFu(std::function<void()> f) { std::invoke(std::move(f)); }
```

and called as

```cpp
useFu([&]{ impl.fu(); });
```

(Rather than using a lambda you can bind the method to the object with `std::bind` in the latter call but almost nobody ever does that.)

Comment: Using somthing like `inv.useFu(&Impl::fu);` is fine, but it couses error `no matching function for call to 'Inv::useFu(void (Impl::*)())' `.

Comment: Forgot `static_cast`, sorry.

Comment: How I then can use `fu()` itself? I need to use it as a pointer to member function.

Comment: Actualy I`ll pass `fu()` further in `useFu()` as pointer.